# In doctrine, Is it good practice to write insert queries in custom repositories

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

In doctrine, I am using custom repositories for select queries, but i want my insert queries also in a centralized location so i want to know that Is it good practice to write insert queries in custom repositories.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: plz share what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

It depends. In some situations you need a custom insert statement, but I would recommend to always let doctrine do the inserts and updates, there is an idea behind that. Doctrine goes through the various listeners, the computed commit order and the DBAL types conversion.